# Solving conflicts with jQuery live() when using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have buttons on a page that is part of the class named "go". I use the following code:

```
$(".go").live('click', this.handleAction);
```

I also have ajax events that will load another piece of HTML and JS that will replace the above buttons and contents, but it also has a piece of code that might be in conflict:

```
$(".go").live('click', this.handleAnotherAction);
```

I know the obvious answer is the change the class name to something else other than "go". But are there other ways to go about doing this without changing the class name of the new AJAX-inserted element? Maybe there is a way to reset the live() bindings?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your explanation is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the `live` bindings from elements, you need to use the `die` unbinding function. Note that your selector to `die` must exactly match the selector used to `live`:

```
// create live bindings:
$(".go").live('click', this.handleAction);

// remove live bindings:
$(".go").die('click');

// you can also specify the method you want to unbind, in case there are multiple live bindings:
$(".go").die('click', this.handleAction);

// rebind to a new live
$(".go").live('click', this.handleAnotherAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right, you need to use die.

Something like:

```
$(".go").die("click")
```

before calling the next live.